# Create a php object from python class

Tags: php, python, class, object

Is there a way that I can create a `php object` from `python class`?
I found that [example](https://www.csh.rit.edu/~jon/projects/pip/):

**The python class :**

```
# module.py
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def returnInt(self):
        return 1113

    def test(self, a, b = 'str'):
        return "a = %d, b = %s" % (a, b)

    def returnMe(self):
        return self

    def returnTuple(self):
        return (1, "two", 3.0)

    def returnList(self):
        return [1, "two", 3.0]

    def returnDict(self):
        d = {}
        d['one'] = 1
        d['two'] = 2
        d['three'] = 3
        return d

    def p(self, var):
        print var
```

**The php script :**

```
<?php
$p = new Python('module', 'TestClass', array(435));
print $p->returnInt() . "\n";
print $p->test(1, 'bar') . "\n";

print $p->foo . "\n";
$p->foo = 987;
print $p->foo . "\n";

# $copy points to the same object
$copy = $p->returnMe();
print $copy->foo . "\n";
$p->foo = 987;
print $copy->foo . "\n";
?>
```

But it didn't work.

I get this error message:

> Class 'Python' not found in C:\wamp\www\MDASA\public\tst.php

So my question is: is that code is right or is it not if there is a way to create a php object from python class?

Comment: Did you install the extension from the linked page? http://pecl.php.net/package/python

Comment: witch extension ?

Comment: You might want to reconsider using an extension that hasn't been updated in more than 9 years: It is very likely that both PHP and Python have evolved a bit...

Comment: I'd even dare to say that the whole concept seems quite brittle to me.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Too subtle? ;-)

Comment: I download it, then what should i do next ?

Comment: I found that comand [pecl install python](https://github.com/jparise/php-python#installation) but where I run it ?

Comment: A minimal [improvement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) of your writing quality would help your question a lot.

Comment: @peterh Than you, I will keep that in my mind :)